# How to write dependsOn in Custom plugin

Tags: plugins, groovy, gradle

I have a task in my build.gradle :

```
task makeJar(type: Copy) {
delete('dist/')
from('build/intermediates/bundles/release')
into('dist/')
include('classes.jar')
def jarName = new VersionName().getNameWithVersion() + '.jar'  
rename('classes.jar', jarName)
}
makeJar.dependsOn('clearTask', build)
```

Now, I want to remove this from my build.gradle and create a custom plugin like this : MakeJarTask.groovy  (this is in eclipse project)

```
class MakeJarPluginTask extends Copy{
@TaskAction
def makeJar(){
    logger.lifecycle("creating a jar *********************")
    delete('dist/')
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release')
    into('dist/')
    include('classes.jar')
            def jarName = new VersionName().getNameWithVersion() + '.jar'
    rename('classes.jar', jarName)
 }
```

Calling this Task in callGroovy.class (that implements Plugin)

```
project.tasks.create("makeJarPlugin1", MakeJarPluginTask.class){
 dependsOn("clearDist", "build")
}
```

But this doesn't give the correct output .
The error is in last part, I think this is not the correct way to use dependsOn but I am not able to get how to use this. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Task task = project.tasks.create("makeJarPlugin1", MakeJarPluginTask.class);
task.dependsOn("clearDist", "build")
```

Comment: Is there a way to make "clearDist", "build" etc, a sent in parameter instead?

Comment: Where do you do this in your custom plugin? in the method annotated with `@TaskAction` this is too late. In the constructor of the task you do not have access to the input values.

Comment: I have opened this question as follow-up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70695694