# Using `dependsOn` from within a custom plugin, Gradle

Tags: gradle

Possible duplicate: [How to write dependsOn in Custom plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35195702/how-to-write-dependson-in-custom-plugin)

I've got a custom Gradle plugin with two tasks, A and B. I declare the two tasks like this in my plugin:

```
project.task('A') << {      
   ....
}
project.task('B') << {      
   ....
}
```

How can I make task `B` `dependOn` task `A`? Usually you can say `task myTask(dependsOn: 'myOtherTask')`, but the syntax requirements for working within a plugin don't seem to allow this type of dependency declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
project.task('B', dependsOn: project.property('A')) ) << {      
   ....
}
```